# Removing last element of Singly linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Following is my try : -

```
public void removeTail(){
    Node precurrent=null;
    Node transverse=head;
    if(size != 0) {
        while(transverse.getNext() !=null) {
            System.out.println("oh"+transverse.getElement());
            precurrent=transverse;
            transverse=transverse.getNext();
        }
        precurrent.setNext(null);
        size--;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("List is all ready empty");
    }
}
```

The problem with above code is that it gives error when there is only one node left and I try to remove it. This is because of the way I defined precurrent. Kindly suggest what should be done to handle this case. I don't want to add the case of size==1.

Comment: Really? Out of the thousands of examples of linked lists that would be returned on google, none of them helped?

Comment: Hmm you never **remove** anything, you only iterate

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev  : I am setting reference of second last node to null. It is equivalent of removing last node. Or i should improve on it ?

Comment: @Addict sorry you are right. I saw the problem now - you never modify head(and you should if size is now 0). Also when the size is 1 there is no second to last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways.

Either check if your size equals to 1.

Or and this would be my solution, initialize `precurrent` with `head` just like you did it with `transverse`

Comment: second option seems graceful